# nHibernate errors that a column is set twice while updating a record

Tags: c#, asp.net, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, entities

How To Update a Record using Hibernate Mapping of the entity with Composite ID
I have this mapping class in nhibernate.

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" schema="dbo" namespace="XXX.Core.Entities" assembly="FSI.Core.Entities">
  <class name="RoleGroupLink" table="RoleGroupLink">
    <composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one name="RoleGroup" class="RoleGroup" column="RoleGroupID"  />
      <key-many-to-one name="Role" class="Role" column="RoleID" />
      <key-property name="ObjectID" type="Int32" column="ObjectID" />
      <key-property name="ObjectName" type="AnsiString" column="ObjectName" length="100" />
      <key-property name="RoleID" type="AnsiString" column="RoleID" />
      <!--type="Int32"-->
      <key-property name="RoleGroupID" type="AnsiString" column="RoleGroupID" />
      <!--type="Int32"-->
    </composite-id>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to save or update a entity using this method it errors as below, 
Nhibernate Exception.

The column name 'RoleID' is specified more than once in the SET clause. 
A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same SET clause. 
Modify the SET clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If the SET clause updates columns of a view, then the column name 'RoleID' may appear twice in the view definition.
The column name 'RoleGroupID' is specified more than once in the SET clause. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same SET clause. Modify the SET clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If the SET clause updates columns of a view, then the column name 'RoleGroupID' may appear twice in the view definition.

I have also tried with these xml attributes but my application complains about the insert and update to be unknown any Ideas?

Comment: I am using this in the asp.net c# Web Applicaiton.

Comment: Can you had the Role class mapping, are you updating the class Role or just the link?

Comment: Role Is not Updated. 
Crash happens in the update of the RoleGroupLink

Comment: @hussian - its some-kind your child entities are saving reverse you need to set `insert-false` and/or `update=false` see here: www.andriybuday.com/2009/12/nhibernate-column-name-columnid-is.html